# django wsgi.py cannot recognize settings file

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

A strange problem occured while trying to configure `apache2` to serve a Django project via `wsgi`.

My project is a small to-do list implemented here. https://github.com/panospet/toDoList

When apache tries to run `wsgi.py`, returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/toDoList/myToDoList/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named myToDoList.settings
```

My `wsgi.py` file is like:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(' /var/www/toDoList')
sys.path.append(' /var/www/toDoList/myToDoList')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myToDoList.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and also my `.conf` file inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/toDoList"
    ServerName blahblah
    WSGIDaemonProcess todolist user=test group=test threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/toDoList/myToDoList/wsgi.py
    <Location /todolist>
        WSGIProcessGroup todolist
    </Location>
    <Directory /var/www/toDoList/toDoList>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/toDoList/myToDoList/static/
    <Directory /var/www/toDoList/myToDoList/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove that space in sys.path.append

```
sys.path.append('/var/www/toDoList')
sys.path.append('/var/www/toDoList/myToDoList')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) You missed the `WSGIPythonPath`:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/toDoList
```

This line ensures that your project package is available for import on the Python path; in other words, that import mysit works.

Comment: Adding it to ``sys.path`` in the WSGI script file serves the same purpose. Provided they didn't include the spaces as noted by someone else.